# Installing MSSQL functions in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, macos

I'm trying to connect to my SQL server through PHP. Obviously using MySQL php functions do not work, how do I go about installing MSSQL functions for PHP on OSX? After exhausting google, I thought there would be a lot more tutorials are resources available which suggests to me this isn't the best way to connect to an SQL server.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What OS ...and did you [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php)?

Comment: Hey Dave, I'm using Mac OSX 10.6. And yeah I read that, and had a look over freetds which seemed too complicated. How do you personally go about it?

Comment: I have never done this before (never needed to) but if your still having trouble on Monday I will have a go with it and report back... I have a couple of OSX 10.6 machines at the office but none available here (I'm all Fedora and Win32 at home)

Comment: That would be great Dave, thanks so much! Contact me via email if you like.

Comment: FYI I haven't forgotten about this, I've just had a real problem getting it to work. I managed to get `phpinfo()` showing the MSSQL extension as being available, but I keep getting seg faults (SIGSEGV) every time I actually try and use it. I'll let you know if I ever get anywhere with it...

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
function read($id){
$myServer = "xx.xx.x.x";
$myUser = "us";
$myPass = "pas";
$myDB = "db";


//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

$dbhandle =  mssql_select_db($myDB,$dbhandle);

echo "Connected";

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = " SELECT col1 from table1";

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" .$numRows. ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>";

//display the results
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
...
}


//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
}
```

For further detail, see this link

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: Isn't he asking how to install/configure the MSSQL extension, rather than how to use it?

Comment: Precisely :) Thanks for your help though Adeel, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

ps: mssql (at least 5 years ago) was a lot slower than mysql in doing simple stuff(SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE). mssql had the advantage of views and pretty human stored procedures... but speed was more important...

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php

Disclaimer: never used them

What have you tried until now?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, nothing else. What's the best way these days?

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP Manual...

> To use the MSSQL extension on Unix/Linux, you first need to build and
>   install the FreeTDS library. Source code and installation instructions
>   are available at the FreeTDS home page: » http://www.freetds.org/

I have never even tried to do this but just had a look and it seems to be fairly comprehensively documented - although it does assume you know a little bit about building from source on *nix... You will also need gcc or similar...

Answer (score -1):

You need to ensure that PHP has been compiled with MySQL support, or that you have enabled the MySQL extension. You can check your PHP.ini file to determine if you need to uncomment those lines or not. Usually this is the case.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL.